# Bootcamp and upgrading to macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, bootcamp

At the moment, I am running OS X El Capitan (10.11.5) and Windows 10 in bootcamp on my MacBook Pro. I plan on upgrading to the macOS Sierra public beta when it comes out in July or so.

My question is, is an upgrade to macOS Sierra going to make my bootcamp not bootable anymore. I have seen on apple discussion forums, and people that I know have had problems getting their bootcamp to work after an OS X upgrade. However, I have also seen many others not having any issues whatsoever when upgrading.

I would just like to clear up my confusion, will an upgrade from El Capitan to macOS sierra render my bootcamp useless/unbootable?

Comment: Golden rule for any mission-critical system... don't play with betas. Wait for the release & then wait a bit more. Let someone else find out what doesn't work first.

Comment: Yeah, I might not upgrade to macOS Sierra right away. I think I can wait :)

Comment: And someone just answered it who has tested on sierra. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running a macOS Sierra Seed Beta (invitation-only, released before the public beta) and my VMs and other bootable OS', including bootcamp are working just fine. But as always, you will be on a beta so proceed with caution!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question so fast. I think I might upgrade in July then

Comment: No problem. Either way, I don't anticipate issues because boot camp assistant creates a new partition that doesn't really associate with the Mac OS. You might have trouble creating a new partition if Apple releases a version with a bug in BootCamp Assistant, but created partitions should remain intact. Again, proceed with caution.

Comment: It is telling me to wait a few minutes but I will accept it :)

Comment: Also, did you have bootcamp running before the upgrade to macOS sierra?

Comment: Yes, I had created my partition when I was running El Capitan. I'm running through bootcamp now and it seems to be letting me create another one without issues, so you should be fine, unless they screw it up in a later version, which has happened before. But they're more cautious on public betas.

Answer (score 0):

It is a beta it might or it might not. Until Apple makes it public we cannot know.

It will depend on what they want to test first - it could be that Bootcamp will be fixed in a later part of the beta and be broken at the beginning

Anyway assume,e you will have to restore from a good backup and make that part of your workflow

Comment: Yeah, I always try to have a backup on hand if I mess anything up. (Which tends to happen) :)